# Add a link to the reputation tab from the profile page

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, profile-page

If I visit someone's profile page, and I am shown the Profile page which summaries their activity and whatnot, I can access the badges and the posts and the tags all fine.

But there is no direct link to the reputation page. Not one I could find, anyway. So in order to see recent reputation changes it is necessary to go through the activity page first.

> Please add a link to the reputation tab directly from the profile page.

Comment: Where in the page should that link be?

Comment: Perhaps the reputation score, or the word "reputation", or both...

Comment: actually you can click on the reputation graphic (in the activity tab) to see the reputation changes of a user.

Comment: @timmbob: Yes, but if you're on the activity page you can also just click the reputation tab itself. I'm talking about adding a link to the *profile* page, which is what you see when you visit other users' user page.

Comment: In hindsight the "prototyping" of the new profile/activity tabs on Meta.SE did not give a realistic feel for how it would work with Community sites or their "child meta's".  I'm still stumbling about for ways to navigate quickly, or in patterns that replaced my habitual movements.

Comment: The larger issue is that the Profile tab is useless. There's a [userscript](http://stackapps.com/a/6268/26164) to always open Activity tab by default. (I'm not very happy with its performance, but it seems to work for others.)